# playframework: Is NingWSClient thread safe?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, asynchttpclient

Say I have

`val client = new NingWSClient((new AsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder).build)`

Is it thread-safe to use `client` all over the current JVM?

Answer (score 0):

Will Sargent has answered the question in Play Framework group conversation, and - yes, it is safe!

Will, thanks!